# Connection of websocket with an android application

Tags: react-native, asp.net-core, signalr

I have an error when trying to connect:

`ReactNativeJS: [12:52:08 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'chathub'.
ReactNativeJS: [12:52:08 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: Negotiating with 'http://10.0.2.2:50069/chathub/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D'.
ReactNativeJS: 'SignalR error: Error during negotiation request.', ''
ReactNativeJS: Failed
ReactNativeJS: [12:52:08 GMT+0000 (GMT)] SignalR: Stopping connection.`

Server:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs (Unbound entries are omitted)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddSignalR();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, DataContext context)
{
    // global cors policy
    app.UseCors(x => x
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowCredentials());

    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
    });
}
```

React-native:

```
import signalr from 'react-native-signalr';

export default class Settings extends Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    //This is the server under /example/server published on azure.
    const connection = signalr.hubConnection('http://10.0.2.2:50069/chathub');
    connection.logging = true;

    const proxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
    //receives broadcast messages from a hub function, called "helloApp"
    proxy.on('SendMessage', (argOne, argTwo, argThree, argFour) => {
      console.log('message-from-server', argOne, argTwo, argThree, argFour);
      //Here I could response by calling something else on the server...
    });

    // atempt connection, and handle errors
    connection.start().done(() => {
      console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id);

      proxy.invoke('sendMessage', 'Hello Server, how are you?', 'ffff')
        .done((directResponse) => {
          console.log('direct-response-from-server', directResponse);
        }).fail(() => {
          console.warn('Something went wrong when calling server, it might not be up and running?')
        });

    }).fail(() => {
      console.log('Failed');
    });

    //connection-handling
    connection.connectionSlow(() => {
      console.log('We are currently experiencing difficulties with the connection.')
    });

    connection.error((error) => {
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      let detailedError = '';
      if (error.source && error.source._response) {
        detailedError = error.source._response;
      }
      if (detailedError === 'An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.') {
        console.log('When using react-native-signalr on ios with http remember to enable http in App Transport Security https://github.com/olofd/react-native-signalr/issues/14')
      }
      console.debug('SignalR error: ' + errorMessage, detailedError)
    });
  }
    render(){
        return(
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I do everything as it should be but I do not want to make a connection. I am using Windows 10.

Maybe I forget something in the code?

................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to use an ASP.NET **Core** SignalR server with an ASP.NET SignalR Client. Core and non Core versions of the client and server are incompatible.

From the [MSDN SignalR alpha blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/)

> SignalR for ASP.NET Core is not compatible with previous versions of
>   SignalR. This means that you cannot use the old server with the new
>   clients or the old clients with the new server.